# C character array comparison

Tags: c

Ok so I was doing a coding challenge on codewars.com and the challenge was to take a string as input and return a string where in place of the letters are instead the number of the alphabet that matches the letter.

Everything except letters are to be ignored.

ex: "aab" would return "1 1 2"

There should be a space between each number that represents a letter in the alphabet.

So, when I run this code on my IDE (which is xcode using c99) Everything looks good and the `strcmp()` function says the 2 strings are equal.
The website I'm on uses C11 I believe but I don't see that causing the error.

When I run this code on the challenge website it passes a couple of tests but then fails a couple also. It fails when the input string is "", and it also fails on the string that I have used in the code below, but again it does not fail when I run it on my ide.

My questions are:

1) Any idea what is causing this bug?

2) What would you have done differently as far as the code is concerned

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *alphabet_position(char *text)
{
    int i,letter_position;
    unsigned long int size = strlen(text);

    char *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*size + 1);

    char int_string[10];
    char temp = ' ';

    //If String wasn't blank
    if (strcmp(text, "")!=0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        {
            //If it is a letter
            if (isalpha(text[i]))
            {
                temp = tolower(text[i]);
                if (temp == 'a')
                    strcat(result, "1");
                else
                {
                    letter_position = temp - 'a' + 1;
                    sprintf(int_string,"%d",letter_position);
                    strcat(result, int_string);
                }
                //Print space after letter until the last letter
                if (i!=size-2)
                    strcat(result, " ");
            }
        }
        strcat(result, "\0");
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(result, "\0");
        return result;
    }

}


int main(void)
{

    char *string = alphabet_position("The narwhal bacons at midnight.");
    char *expected_output = "20 8 5 14 1 18 23 8 1 12 2 1 3 15 14 19 1 20 13 9 4 14 9 7 8 20";

    printf("Your output %s\n", alphabet_position("The narwhal bacons at midnight."));
    printf("Expt output %s\n", "20 8 5 14 1 18 23 8 1 12 2 1 3 15 14 19 1 20 13 9 4 14 9 7 8 20");

    printf("\n");

    printf("your len %lu\n", strlen(alphabet_position("The narwhal bacons at midnight.")));
    printf("Expt len %lu\n", strlen(expected_output));

    if (strcmp(string, expected_output)==0)
        printf("Equal\n");
    else
        printf("Not equal\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized the contents of `result`, so `strcat(result, "1");` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why is your loop only up to `size-1`? You're ignoring the last character of the input string.

Comment: There's no need for `strcat(result, "\0");`. All the previous calls to `strcat()` will add a null terminator.

Comment: Why do you have a special case for `temp == 'a'`? Your general calculation `temp - 'a' + 1` will work for it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for pointing all that out. I don't really know why I did the size-1, I think I was trying to fix an earlier problem and forgot to take it back out. As far as the strcat function, I did not know it null terminated it automatically. And the temp=='a', your right about that too. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar I thought when I used malloc in the result declaration that was initializing it? I'm fairly new at C

Comment: This is an odd way to allocate memory for your result: `char *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*size + 1)`.  --> You are using `sizeof(int)` but the result is a `char` buffer.  It "works" because `sizeof(int)` >= `3*sizeof(char)` on your system.  Every character gets replaced with up to 3 characters: ie: `z` -> `26 ` (characters 2, 6, and a space).

Comment: set `result[0] = 0` after the malloc.  This will make it a null terminated empty string that you can then pass to 'strcat'

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int)*size + 1)` this is just wrong. You don't want to allocate a buffer for array of `size` variable of `int` type and one byte more. You need to allocate as many bytes you need for the output. Not for `int` array.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I wasn't really sure the right way to do it because it was a char array, but when I was trying to put integers in it to return the result I was getting a buffer overflow. I was trying to make it where every spot had enough space to store an integer.

Comment: The posted code does not implement the terms of the challenge, so everything would fail.  Please post the code you actually used -or- post the actual text of the challenge

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  besides the problems with the logic (as documented else where) this statement: `for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)` and this statement: `if (i!=size-2) each result in the compiler outputting a message similar to: *:34:22: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two serious problems.

First, you're not initializing the contents of the `result` array to an empty string. After you call `malloc()`, add:

```
result[0] = '\0';
```

`malloc()` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates. There's another function `calloc()` that takes slightly different arguments and initializes the memory to zeroes. But you only need the first character to be zero, so there's no need for that.

Second, the `for` loop is not processing the last character of `text`. It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Similarly, the test for whether to add a space should be `if (i != size-1)`. Did you think `strlen()` counts the null character at the end?

The amount of space you specify in `malloc()` is not correct, but in practice it won't cause a problem. `sizeof(int)` has nothing to do with the number of characters it takes to show the value of an integer. Since you're just printing the alphabetical position, it will be at most `26`, so you need 3 characters for every input character. Therefore, it should be:

```
char *result = malloc(3 * size + 1);
```

Your allocation works because `sizeof(int)` is generally at least 4, so you're allocating more than enough space.

There are other minor problems that don't affect the correctness of the result:

You don't need the `if` statement that treats `'a'` specially, the code you have in `else` will work for all letters.

You don't need `strcat(result, "\0")` at the end. `result` has to already be null-terminated in order for you to use it as an argument to `strcat()`, so there's no point in using `strcat()` to add a null terminator.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, you cleared up some of the confusion I was having about initializing char arrays as well as some of the other unnecessary code that was in there. I had no idea strcat added a null terminator either lol.

Comment: I think this introduces a subtle bug when the input doesn't end with a letter. There will be an extra space at the end of the output string.

Comment: Yeah. A simpler solution would be to put space after every number, and at the end overwrite the last space with a null byte.

Comment: Another method would be to write the space *before* each number, unless it's the first number being printed.

Comment: `Your allocation works because sizeof(int) is generally at least 4, so you're allocating more than enough space.`, actually that explains why it fails on an empty string.

Comment: @Jasen That will fail the same way no matter what you multiply by.